# Hbase - copy one row from one table to another in diff env - Java

Tags: java, hbase

I created `HBaseConfiguration` for `both the environments`.

```
Get g =  new Get(Bytes.toByte("rowKey"));
Result r = envATable.get(g);

Put p = new Put(Bytes.toByte("sameRowKey"));
p.add("Need a way to add that result");
envBTable.put(p);
```

Solutions I found:

Iterate result, add each `KeyValue` into `p`.

Is there anyother way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using get, the result should contain one row. For a put, all you need is a row key, and then list of col family, qualifier, value.

```
String rowId = new String(result.getRow());
Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowId));
for(Cell cell : result.rawCells()) {
    put.add(CellUtil.cloneFamily(cell), 
    CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell), CellUtil.cloneQualifier(cell));
}
envBTable.put(put);
```

CellUtil is the way to extract the cell details. I hope you know every cell has detail about rowkey, family, qualifier, timestamp and value. You can get the row key from each cell, too but its logical to get it for entire row. I hope this helps.

And as long as you have envBTable set up, any server is same i suppose, given you have permission for the user.

if you are using shell, approach might be different. But eventually you might need a script there too, as you have to customize and there is no standard way of do this i suppose

Comment: I am not able to use Cellutil, Eclipse suggests CellSet.

Comment: My Hbase version 0.95.10

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at replication as an alternative? You can enable replication for particular column families in HBase.

Comment: Nice one. I am new to all these concepts. But replication requires more changes in the existing cluster. So I don't want that now. Since I require only one row